# Convert to parse tree with POS tag

Tags: python, nlp, context-free-grammar, pos-tagger, dependency-parsing

I used [pystatParser](https://github.com/emilmont/pyStatParser) to generate each parse tree for a English sentence.
Example output (just an example):

```
(NP+S (NP (DT every) (NN cat)) (VP (VB loves) (NP (DT a) (NN dog))))
```

How to convert every output into the below style:

```
(S (NP (DET Every) (NN cat)) (VP (VT loves) (NP (DET a) (NN dog))))
```

Thanks!

Comment: It seems to me you have to follow a simple mapping process, e.g. DT->DET, VB->VT etc. What is the problem?

Comment: I want to modify the output of the Parser i mentioned, but i dont know how to do that.

Comment: If all you want is to change the POS labels, these are defined in stat_parser/treebanks/parse.py.